# Listening to the mousescroll event jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

im trying to create a website that listens to the scrolling event of the entire website. The website in question is [exora-it.nl](http://exora-it.nl). As you can see when scrolling down is that the mousetracking function updates ONLY after moving your mouse.

My problem is that I want it to happen on actually scrolling down/up the website, so that the overall image is smoother. Anyone who can help me out?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using jQuery, you can simply do this:

```
$( window ).scroll(function() {
    // Do something
});
```

Comment: I understand that this fires the `Do something` at the end of scrolling. Is there also a way to fire it during scrolling?

Comment: Actually, this will keep firing during the scrolling. I can't tell you how many times it will fire though, if it's once per pixel scrolled or something else, but you can rely on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can track the scrolling offset of the current window:

```
   var offsetX=window.pageXOffset
   var offsetY=window.pageYOffset
```

And then add this offset to the position of whatever element you're trying to move.